# Настройка шардирования PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Всем привет.
Возможно ли настроить кластер PostgreSQL так, что бы конкретная схема PostgreSQL находилась на определённом сервере (либо на нескольких).

Answer (score 0):

Нет.

Но есть ряд проектов с такими возможностями

https://github.com/citusdata/pg_shard/

https://www.citusdata.com/

http://www.postgres-xl.org/overview/